# How to fix TypeError Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test cases using Jest in my Angular project and I encounter these error when ever I try to run my test file

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'enhancement' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bug' of undefined
```

I'm reading those property in my HTML files and I thought If I create a mock data in side spec.ts file then it should fix it but I'm not sure why I'm still getting those errors.

Editor-Dialog.component.ts

```
export class EditorDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  post: PostSection = {
    title: '',
    release: {
      features: null,
      enhancements: null,
      bug: null,
    },
    blog: null,
    type: 1,
  };
```

In my Editor-Dialog.html I'm reading it like this

```
  <ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post.release.features"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription"></ngx-wig>
  <ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post.release.enhancements"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription"></ngx-wig>
  <ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post.release.bus"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription"></ngx-wig>
```

this is a snippet of my test file Editor-Dialog.spec.ts

```
// I have created mock data in this file

  it('should create', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorDialogComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.post = testPost;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I've uploaded these components full code here so I'll be really appreciated if anyone can take a look at it and help me fix it even thought you'll not able to run the project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dv2dha?file=editor-dialog.html

Comment: You should not use ngModel and formControl in same element. either you use ngModel Or formControl.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code+test step by step? Which line throw the error? What does testPost looks like?

Comment: may be testPost does not contain expected data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }
Here you should pass the testPost

Answer (score 0):

Add ngIf condition before using the respective variables, to make sure the variable is available.

For Example,

```
<ngx-wig *ngIf="post && post.release"
          [(ngModel)]="post.release.features"></ngx-wig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes and you are good to go:

```
<ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post?.release?.features"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription">
</ngx-wig>
<ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post?.release?.enhancements"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription">
</ngx-wig>
<ngx-wig
          [(ngModel)]="post?.release?.bus"
          formControlName="enhancementDescription">
</ngx
```